# how to add color to symbol used in chemdown command?

Tags: color, chemfig

I'm trying to color the "]" symbol used in the "\chemdown" command (package chemfig, \chemdown] ).
When I get it colored, the "]" symbol becomes small, much smaller than the molecule above it.

Any suggestion?

This code don't worked

```
\chemup.
    \chemfig{H_3C-COOH}
    \color{blue}\chemdown]
```

not this one either

```
\chemup.
    \chemfig{H_3C-COOH}
    {\color{blue}\chemdown]}
```

A "MacGyverism" is in the code below, inspired by polyn's response. But it's not the same as coloring the "]" symbol, and it doesn't work if you want to use the "}" symbol.

```
\chemfig{H_3C-@{b}COOH}
%
\arrow(@{b}--){0}[270,.05]\chemfig{(-[0,2,,,,blue,thick]-[2,.3,,,,blue,thick])-[4,1.8,,,,,blue,thick]-[2,.3,,,,blue,thick]}
```

[image]

Comment: Code? Makes things easier :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\textcolor{red}{\chemup.\chemfig[chemfig style=black]{H_3C-COOH}\chemdown]}
\schemestop

\bigskip

\schemestart
\subscheme{\chemfig{H_3C-COOH}}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw[-, red, semithick] ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}]c1.south west) -- ++(0,-3pt) -| ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]c1.south east);}

\bigskip

\schemestart
\subscheme{\chemfig{H_3C-COOH}}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw[-, pen colour={blue}, decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=3pt, mirror}, thick] ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}]c1.south west) -- ([shift={(2pt,-2pt)}]c1.south east);}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** (an addition of a calligraphic brace)

[image]